# How am I supposed to reach a captive portal's login page when all my favorite sites use HSTS?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssl, https, captive-portal, hsts

So I wanted to use the WiFi somewhere with a captive portal today. No problem, right? I'll just open my browser, type in `www.google.com`, and see the login page for the WiFi.

Wrong! My browser wants to connect to Google by HTTPS, and that prevents the captive portal from intercepting my traffic to Google. I try some other sites that I can think of. They also all use HTTPS to connect. Finally, I try `http://www.intel.com/`, a site that I can think of but never visit. It works. I get the captive portal. Then at some point, I disconnect from the WiFi network and have to try again. This time, it turns out that `www.intel.com` has sent an [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) header has telling my browser that in the future, it should only use HTTPS to connect to `www.intel.com`.

If most or all websites want me to connect via HTTPS these days, how am I supposed to reach the captive portal's login page?

Comment: See my answer [Are there well known HTTP-only sites?](//superuser.com/a/1213128)

Comment: Short answer: Use http://neverssl.com/